# Using file find to grab source files

Tags: perl

I am trying to use (as an exercise) the file find callback capability to filter source files out. It does not work so far and just grab everything under the sun.

could you point me out in the good direction ?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my @srcFiles;
my @srcExt = qw(cpp h py pl);


my @startDir = qw(.);
find( sub{
        my @fields = split /'.'/, $File::Find::name;
        push @srcFiles, $File::Find::name if grep $fields[-1], @srcExt;
    }, 
    @startDir);
print 'Source files found: ', @srcFiles;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in your split

```
 my @ar =  split /'.'/, $File::Find::name;
                   ^
            here is your problem.
```

you want to split the file using dot so, you tried `'.'`. But it is not escaping. Escape the character use back slash. So syntax should be

```
my @ar =  split /\./, $File::Find::name;
```

So your code is,

```
find( sub{
     my @fields = split /\./, $File::Find::name;
     push @srcFiles, $File::Find::name if grep $fields[-1], @srcExt;
 }, 
 @startDir);
```

Or else try something as follow, this is more effective than your code and it will fix some bugs as @hobbs mentioned in a comment.

Join the array by the pipe separated. Then use precompiled regex(qr) to add the non capturing group. Then parse variable into the subroutine and check it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my @srcFiles;
my @srcExt = qw(cpp h py pl);
my $match = join("|",@srcExt);
$match = qr/\.(?:$match)$/;

my @startDir = qw(.);

find(sub
{
    my $s = $File::Find::name;
    push(@srcFiles,$s) if($s =~m/$match/);

}
, @startDir);

print @srcFiles;
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Do you know what is the error in my version ? Basically what I tried to do is split the filename on '.',  get the last field (extension) and  try to match any extensions against it.
I understand your approach but I'd like to correct mine too.

Comment: @zebullon the `grep` is also wrong — the `if` condition will be true as long as `$fields[-1]` is any true value and `@srcExt` is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
my @fields = split /'.'/, $File::Find::name;
```

This regular expression splits the filename where it finds an apostrophe, followed by any character, followed by an apostrophe. This is definitely not what you intended.

Instead, try:

```
my @fields = split /\./, $File::Find::name;
```